# Sorting in sparse matrix (Python 2.*)

Tags: python, scikit-learn, sparse-matrix, python-2.x

I'm solving a task in coursera and get stuck with sorting in sparse matrix.
The problem is: i make a support vector classification (`sklearn.svm.SVC`)

```
    clf = SVC(C=1, kernel='linear', random_state=241)
    clf.fit(X, y)
```

and as a result got a matrix `clf.coef_` of `[index_id; weight]`.
Now i need to extract top N weight and their indices, but `weights` sorting with `clf.coef_.argsort()` does not lead to simultaneous `index_id` sorting.
How can i sort this matrix not breaking `[index_id; weight]` link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since by calling `argsort` you get the sorted indices instead of the sorted array, you can use the result of `argsort` directly as feature indices.

So if you have an array `[1.5, 2.5, 0.5]`, the result of `argsort` is `[2, 0, 1]`, representing that element at index 2 is the lowest element, index 0 is the second lowest, and index 1 is the highest.

So if you want to extract top-2, you take the last two entries of the array returned by `argsort` and reversed it as the feature indices, in this case `[1, 0]`

This is what I usually do to extract top-N weights from linear SVM:

```
coefs = clf.coef_
if len(set(labels)) == 2:
    coefs = np.array([coefs[0, :], (1-coefs)[0, :]])
for cls, coef in zip(sorted(set(labels)), coefs):
    top_k = reversed(np.argsort(coef)[-k:])
    keywords = [mapping[idx] for idx in top_k]
    print('%s: %s' % (cls, keywords))
```

Where `labels` is the set of classes, and `mapping` is the feature index to feature name (usually words) mapping.

Comment: So, `mapping` is `vectorizer.get_feature_names()`, and what should i put into `labels`? (yep, i am complete newbie to python). The code i am using is follows: http://pastebin.com/kxt0Rr35

Comment: It's the set of classes that you classify the input into.

Comment: Looks like i've overcomed it with


       `inds = clf.coef_.indices[clf.coef_.data.argsort()[-10:]]`
       `print(sorted(feature_mapping[i] for i in inds))`

Thank you